# how to create a order which contains multiple NFT item for sale and match this order

Tags: blockchain, web3js, nft, opensea

I want to create a OpenSea order which package quotes for multiple items

```
// javascript

// client uses this method to create sale-multiple-NFTS order
async function createMultipleOrder( ) {

//  offerItemList like this  -> different NFT type
const nftList= [

// tokenAddres: 0x10b8b56d53bfa5e374f38e6c0830bad4ebee33e6
{
  itemType: ItemType.ERC721,
  token: "0x10b8b56d53bfa5e374f38e6c0830bad4ebee33e6",
  identifier: "001",
},
{
  itemType: ItemType.ERC721,
  token: "0x10b8b56d53bfa5e374f38e6c0830bad4ebee33e6",
  identifier: "002",
},

// tokenAddres: 0xbb1594Cc5C456541B02A24a9132B070B385B7035 
{
  itemType: ItemType.ERC721,
  token: "0x10b8b56d53bfa5e374f38e6c0830bad4ebee33e6",
  identifier: "002",
}

];

const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });


const saleAccount = accounts[0];
const buyerAccount =  '0x00....';


const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const seaport = new Seaport(provider);

const { executeAllActions } = await seaport.createOrder(
    {
      offer: nftList,

      consideration: [
        {
          
          // NFTS for 1 ETH 
          amount: ethers.utils.parseEther("1").toString(),
          recipient: buyerAccount ,
        },
      ],
    },
    saleAccount ,
  );

   const order = await executeAllActions();

}
  console.log(order);
```

order contains a var => signature

then  use the method matchOrder to fulfull this order.

the question is , Any account  can use the method createOrder , but only the NFT owner can match this order ??

Now , I can use the openSea SDK to create a sellOrder or buyOrder when I create, the openSea WebSite will display this list or offer, but use the seaportJS's method createOrder how to create a order contains multiple NFT items for sale ??